# Image caching on Client Side

Tags: c#, vb.net, caching, client-side

I'm having a http handler that is retrieving images from the file system on the server. I need to cache these images on the client side(browser). For that thing i'm doing the following code

```
        context.Response.Clear()
        context.Response.ClearHeaders()
        context.Response.ClearContent()
        Dim ImageCacheExpiry = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ImageCacheExpiryDuration")
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)
        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(ImageCacheExpiry))
        context.Response.Cache.VaryByParams(DisplayImage.FileName) = True
        context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DisplayImage.DateModified)
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & DisplayImage.FileName)
        context.Response.ContentType = DisplayImage.MimeType
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(DisplayImage.ImageBytes)
        context.Response.Flush()
        context.Response.Close()
        context.Response.End()
   'DisplayImage is the object that is having all the data of images like
   'DisplayImage.Filename, DisplayImage.FilePathandName, DisplayImage.MimeType etc
```

The thing happening with this is ... When i switch between the tabs its taking it from the cache... but when i hit the browsers refresh button its again going to the file system on the server... Please tell me how to cache these images on the client side.

P.S: Cant do markup caching for all the pages im my application.

Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: That's the way caching works in a browser. When your "Refresh" the page in the browser that browser will disregard any cached data and get fresh data from the server.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar - Usually you have to hold CTRL and press Refresh for the browser to ignore the cache. Just pressing Refresh will usually cause external files to come from the cache.

Comment: @DanTup, "usually" is the keyword here. Refresh means many different things to different browsers. Nonetheless the point is that the behavior is as expected and you can't control the implementation details of every browser and nor should you design a system the relies on such things.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar - Nowhere did I suggest you can control the browsers, I was correcting what you said. Ignoring the cache on a Refresh is *not* the "default behaviour" and I'm sure the majority of browsers *do not* do this. I wasn't suggesting how this should/shouldn't be handled - that's in my answer.

Comment: @DanTup, I didn't say you suggested either :). Some browsers don't have a notion of Ctrl+F5 (Safari and Opera for example), further they send different headers and react and behave differently. That's all I'm trying to get accorss

Answer (score 0):

Depending on browser and browser settings, your browser might be sending an If-Modified-Since request to see if the cached data is stale. You shoudl use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to figure out exactly what your browser is sending (and your server returning). You may need to handle this, and return a 304 (not modified) header.

Comment: The thing is, I'm able to cache the images and get them from the cache while i'm playing around the application...as i see in fiddler....but when i click on browser's refresh button or f5 key its going to the server to get the images...I researched on this and i get know that refreshing the page will definetly go to the server to get the data.... If that is the case why do we do ctrl+F5 to delete the cache...

Comment: It's probably worth looking up exactly what this specific browser does when you press Refresh. It could be that it always goes to e server, but issues an If-Modified-Since request, whereas Ctrl+Refresh might discard the cache and *always* get a new page. Handling If-Modified-Since and returning a Not Modified header is probably a good idea if you're trying to save bandwidth/processing.